# jQuery scrollTop equivalent in Prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have this piece of jQuery code:

```
var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
```

How do I have to rewrite it for Prototype? I tried $$(window).scrollTop and $(window).scrollTop, doesnt work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/viewport/

```
document.viewport.getScrollOffsets()['top'];
```